# Difference in Gradient Boosting Models

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, boosting

In the past year, I've seen a number of different gradient boosting machines emerging from different groups. I normally used Xgboost since it trained faster than sklearn's gradient boosting machine. Last year I found people using Lightgbm from microsoft and catboost. Secondly when I use these different methods I get different results apart from speed. In case of random forest the results are mostly same whether I use python or R.

How are these models different from one another and how to determine which one to use for a given problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a nice write-up of the differences between XgBoost, LightGBM and Catboost here: [CatBoost vs. Light GBM vs. XGBoost](https://towardsdatascience.com/catboost-vs-light-gbm-vs-xgboost-5f93620723db)

Regarding your 2nd question, you cannot know a-priori which one will perform better on any given task. So, you either have to try them all and see what works best in each case or trust the one you know best and go with it.